# Shrink range of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

Lets say I have a random number, that goes from `0.0` to `1.0`, and I want to reduce its "range", to, lets say `0.25` to `0.75` respecting its harmony.

What would be the pseudo code for this?

Examples:

> 0.0 in the [0.0, 1.0] range would be 0.25 in the [0.25, 0.75] range
>
> 0.5 would still be 0.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a random number r.
First you shrink the range: r = r * (0.75-0.25).
Now it's in the range [0, 0.5]. Then you shift the range: r = r + 0.25.
Now it's in the range [0.25, 0.75].

Comment: Scale, then translate. Same as with graphics processing (ignoring rotation since this is linear).

Comment: If my number is 0.5, and I do `r = r / (0.75 - 0.25)`, it would be `r = r / 0.5`, and that is 1. Wouldn't it be `r = r * (0.75 - 0.25)`?

Comment: Oh sorry small mistake. Fixed.